# Use Groovy to change inline Jmeter variable JSON obj in Body Data

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Idea is to get Jmeter variable `notification` which is JSON obj, edit `notification.isRead` prop and parse it back to string for posting. But something is wrong with assign operator. With `=` I get nothing, without returns parsed JSON (as expected).

With this I am almost there, but I can't figure out how to edit prop `isRead`

```
$ {__groovy
    (
        (
            new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(

                new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('notification')).isRead = false

            ).toPrettyString()
        )
    )
}
```

Obj:

```json
notification: {
    "isRead": false, 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, this would be the correct syntax.

```
${__groovy
(
    def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('notification')) 
    json.isRead = false

    ( new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString())
    )}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case [JsonSlurper.parseText()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html#parseText(java.lang.String)) function returns an instance of [LazyMap](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/apache/groovy/json/internal/LazyMap.html) and changing the value will give you only `true` in case of success.

If you want the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to return the whole amended JSON you need to do something like:

```
${__groovy(notification = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('notification')); notification.isRead = false; return new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(notification).toPrettyString(),)}
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Does this modify the actual variable `notification`?

Comment: it doesn't, only returns the changed JSON

Comment: For the life of me, I can't understand why doesn't your syntax work in Sample's body data. Sample body is blank, no errors though.